# BlueZ Compatible kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am using the kernel version 3.0.35 with bluez-4.98 in linux. With this I'm able to advertise the ibeacon as per the hcitool command given in one of the SO questions.
I am also able to connect to the other ble device but not able to list its services using 'primary' in gatttool.

I want to use my device now as a peripheral to let other device to get its Device Information, and later in the Central mode to know the Device Information of other ble devices.

Will this kernel version and bluez version be compatible for the task?

EDIT: I want the device information like the Firmware Revision, Hardware Revision etc the other characteristics of the DIS service. And how can I update my database for these fields, is it through some xml or some config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there are bugs in LE functionality in versions before 4.101.  You can't use Bluez 5.x in kernels that old, but you should be able to use the latest 4.x version which is 4.101 which may solve your problem.

[Firmware Revision](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.firmware_revision_string.xml), [Hardware Revision String](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.hardware_revision_string.xml), and such can all be requested by their UUID with `gatttool`.  I know nothing about any database you're using.

Comment: I think 4.x versions doesn't have that dependency with the kernel versions. But will I be able to get the Device Information Service through GATT, using the device in peripheral and central mode with bluez-4.101.

Comment: I've had no issues with using GATT in 4.101

Comment: so it can be said that in bluez-4.101 the management interface is implemented in the user space itself rather that the kernel space

Comment: the database i'm talking about is the attribute handles and their values for the characteristics

Comment: i have successfully cross-compiled the bluez 4.101 with the following configure options: disable-usb, disable-cups, disable-udev, disable-systemd, enable-tools, enable-maintainer-mode. With this I got the GATT server running. Ported the binaries on two systems. hciconfig hci0 leadv on one and lescan on the other. I got the bd address of the peripheral in the scan results, but using the gatttool to connect to it, I got into errrors: Device or resource busy or connection refused (111) or connection timed out. I have also tried this with hcitool lecc and also using the --random flag.

Comment: I'm getting the segmentation fault bluetoothd on the peripheral console whenever i try to connect using gatttool from the other side

Comment: okay, now you're getting into other things...  I don't know about running a GATT server with bluez, just that I've had no issues using `gatttool` which is a GATT client.  However, `hciconfig hci0 leadv on` is just going to send out advertising packets, not actually run any sort of GATT server that you can connect to.

Comment: but GATT server runs with the bluetoothd. We can see that from the bluetoothd logs when we run `bluetoothd -n -d &`

Comment: in gatttool also we are getting the errors while connecting, what could be the issue there?

Comment: sorry, you've reached the end of my knowledge...  :)  I've never had to run an GATT server before, so I don't know anything about it.

Comment: getting the segmentation fault in bluetothd and not able to connect can be a bug in bluez-4.101 or am i compiling in some wrong way?

Comment: it's possible, but I've never had issues like that even after manually compiling bluez 4.101

Comment: I have got the device connnected (not everytime) but with `primary' command it doesn't shows up any results :(

Comment: maybe you haven't added any characteristics for the GATT server to share?

Comment: How can we do that? from the logs it seems that Link Loss service and the Immediate alert services are added and handles are also added for them

Comment: again...  I have no knowledge of running a GATT server.  Sorry.

Comment: ok but u have used the 4.101, what services do you see at your end, when you give `primary` command using gatttool and how do you advertise on peripheral?

Comment: not getting the pairing requests while connecting from the android apps like B-BLE or nrfMaster Control Panel

Comment: @tonylin - I never used versions older than 4.101, but older ones were still developing the BLE functionality.  The `gatttool` has buggy/inconsistent parsing in 4.101 and it's even worse in previous versions, for example.  Even 4.101 on older kernels have issues such as not being able to handle more than one BLE connection (in 3.4, at least).