# Bluetooth subsystem in linux and BlueZ

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluez

I'm trying to figure out how the BlueZ userspace library interacts with the Bluetooth subsystem in linux. Specifically, does anyone know answers to the following questions:

- The Bluetooth subsystem version in kernel 4.9 is 2.22. Does there exist a changelog specific for the Bluetooth subsystem?
- Do there exist requirements for a minimum version of the Bluetooth subsystem for a given version of the BlueZ library? E.g. what is the mininum version of the Bluetooth subystem for the latest BlueZ library (v5.43)?

NOTE: The main reason I'm asking is my interest in "experimetnal" BLE features and stuff that has been happening in BlueZ since the 5 release. I've already watched this excellent talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tclS9arLFzk and tried to grasp what sparse information is available from the bluez.org website.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the answer to my own question is this document:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt

I had a very helpful chat on the #bluez freenode channel which is possibly a more proper place for these kinds of questions.

Version 5 and up of bluetoothd (i.e. BlueZ userspace part) should work against any kernel version 3.4 and upwards. However there are some features that are missing unless you use a more recent kernel. Those features are listed in the document linked above.

Answer (score 0):

In the link I posted below it is said that BlueZ utiles interact with kernel with berkley socket interface. It means that BlueZ utiles uses socket systemcalls to interact with kernel. There is also information that

> BlueZ is the official Linux Bluetooth stack

So linux bluetooth subsystem is BlueZ itself.

About LE compability you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609959/bluez-compatible-kernel-version) useful.

[Here](http://www.stlinux.com/kernel/bluetooth/BlueZ-setup) you can find useful information about BlueZ.

Comment: Further more i assume that newest BlueZ library should have backwards compatibility, so latest version of BlueZ library should work with any linux kernel bluetooth subsystem version. But elder BlueZ librarys can expect problems with newer kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The main reason I'm asking is that the Bluetooth subsystem has changed somewhat from the schematic you posted, most notably with the addition of the management interface (https://lwn.net/Articles/531133/). BlueZ 5 library only works with kernel version 3.4 and upwards so there are some caveats to this backwards compatibility. I'm looking into BLE features, namely some that are marked as EXPERIMENTAL in the BlueZ userspace libraries and I'm trying to figure out if the bluetooth code in my kernel version (3.14) is reasonably stable against those methods.