# Bugs in BlueZ 5 LE functionality in linux versions before 4.10

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm new to bluetooth. I'm using tools provided by BlueZ 5 on linux kernel 3.10 and I am wondering the stability of BlueZ running on kernel 3.10. I found an answer on Stackoverflow says

> there are bugs in LE functionality in versions before 4.101. You can't
>   use Bluez 5.x in kernels that old

[BlueZ Compatible kernel version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618434/2279854)

Does anyone know where I can find the bugs that answer is referring to? Or any suggestion of using BlueZ on Linux kernel 3.10? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WTF **v4.101** ? Other than that just read the changelog (commit messages history).

Comment: @0andriy why so rude. Does the changelog contains bug list?